# Positioning of jQuery UI select dropdown is off by 1px in Chrome only

Tags: jquery-ui, select

I have been trying to get my jQuery UI Select dropdown to be aligned on Chrome for some time. Its off by 1px however the list and the parent span.ui-selectmenu-button are both "151px". 
[image]

All other browsers display it correct.

[image]

I've been going through the computer styles one by one but can't find anything.
Its instantiated with the common:

```
 $("#mainlanguage").selectmenu();
```

And the select box which jQuery uses has basic styling on it. (SCSS)
jquery ui language !select

```
.mainSearch{
.ui-selectmenu-button {
    background:$upsbrown;
    outline-style:none!important; // reset

    &.ui-state-hover{
        border:0;
        border-radius:0;
    }
        border:0;
        border-radius:0;
        left: 63.3%;
    span{
        background-color: $upsbrown;
        background-position: 93.5% center;
        //border-top: 1px solid $navtext; 
        color: $navtext;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 18px;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 6px;
        max-width: 151px;
        height: 21px;
        z-index: 400;
        webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        &:focus{
               -webkit-appearance: none;
                -moz-appearance: none;
                appearance: none;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: An online demo demonstrating this issue such as the inbuilt code snippet or jsfiddle with the compiled CSS would be much helpful for those trying to help you...

Comment: Sorry TJ, just looking for any experience I guess.